# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted

Tags: sql

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted
 when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(Select LocationId from Ware.dbo.Dimf l where t.OriginalLocationId = l.LocationId and t.CompanyId = l.CompanyId) as LocationId
, CASE WHEN (Select UnitTypeId from Ware.dbo.DimU ut where t.unit_type = ut.UnitType) IS NULL THEN 9999 ELSE 
(Select UnitTypeId from Ware.dbo.DimU ut where t.unit_type = ut.UnitType) END as UnitTypeId
, CASE WHEN (Select FirmwareId from Ware.dbo.Dimc f where t.FirmwareVersion = f.Firmware and t.CompanyId = f.CompanyId) IS NULL THEN 9999
ELSE 
(Select FirmwareId from Ware.dbo.Dimc f where t.FirmwareVersion = f.Firmware and t.CompanyId = f.CompanyId)
END
as FirmwareId
, ISNULL(t.Installs,0) as Installs

, AddDate = GETDATE()
from #Temp2 t
where (Select LocationId from Ware.dbo.Dimf l where t.OriginalLocationId = l.LocationId and t.CompanyId = l.CompanyId) is not null 
Order by LocationId

Comment: Yes, and what's the question?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: I'm asking if you could help with the rewriting the query

Comment: Where's the query?  How do you expect us to help if all you post is an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of Joins ....... maybe try something like.....

```
Select l.LocationId                as LocationId
    ,  ISNULL(ut.UnitTypeId, 9999) as UnitTypeId
    ,  ISNULL(f.FirmwareId , 9999) as FirmwareId
    ,  ISNULL(t.Installs,0)        as Installs
    ,  GETDATE()                   as AddDate
from #Temp2 t
LEFT JOIN Ware.dbo.Dimf l  ON t.OriginalLocationId = l.LocationId 
                          and t.CompanyId = l.CompanyId
LEFT JOIN Ware.dbo.DimU ut ON t.unit_type = ut.UnitType
LEFT JOIN Ware.dbo.Dimc f  ON t.FirmwareVersion = f.Firmware 
                          and t.CompanyId = f.CompanyId
where l.LocationId is not null 
Order by l.LocationId
```